# NIntegrate: How can I solve this integral numerically? NIntegrate fails while Integrate works

Tags: numerical-integration

I know the exact solution of the principal value of this integral is equal to zero:

$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{y-x}dydx=0$

doing:

```
Integrate[x^2/Sqrt[1 - x^2] Sqrt[1 - y^2]/(y - x), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
PrincipalValue -> True]
```

but I want to do it numerically and it doesn't work:

```
NIntegrate[x^2/Sqrt[1 - x^2] Sqrt[1 - y^2]/(y - x), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

This is the error message returned:

[image]

How can I get *Mathematica* to solve this problem numerically?

Comment: The issue is that the integrand approaches infinity as `x->±1`, `x->y`, and `y->x`. That kind of behavior is toxic to numerical methods: you need to reason out a way to deal with it, not merely probe it numerically. `PrincipalValue -> True` gives you access to automated reasoning in this case, and you've solved the problem that way. Do you have a different problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to solve a similar integral, when x^2 is multplied by exp^(-i*b*(x + y)). So, firstly I wanted to try to solve this known integral.

Comment: Use option Exclusions -> {-1, 1, y + x == 0}]

Comment: All that is built on the sand because the PrincipalValue option for multivariate integrals is undocumented.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the point `x=y`. In principle, it seems that there the integral is singular. If you agree to get the principal value of it, you may exclude this point by a regularization as follows

```
NIntegrate[
 x^2/Sqrt[1 - x^2] Sqrt[1 - y^2]/Sqrt[(y - x)^2 + i^-2], {x, -1 + 1/i,
   1 - 1/i}, {y, -1 + 1/i, 1 - 1/i}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]
```

where `i` is a large number. Then you may increase `i` and check the convergence of the integral:

```
    lst = Table[{1/i, 
         NIntegrate[
          x^2/Sqrt[1 - x^2] Sqrt[1 - y^2]/
            Sqrt[(y - x)^2 + i^-2], {x, -1 + 1/i, 1 - 1/i}, {y, -1 + 1/i, 
           1 - 1/i}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]}, {i, 1000, 100000, 
         1000}] // N;

ListLogPlot[lst /. {x_, y_} -> {1/x, y}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Number i", 16], Style["Integral", 16]}]
```

yielding this

[image]

One can further a few other methods which may eventually enable a more accurate estimate of the integral.

Have fun!

Comment: I don't understand what you're plotting. The value of this integral is 0 and your result is around 12.

Comment: You are right, it is not the same integral, since I took `Sqrt[(x-y)^2+eps^2]` instead of `x-y`.

Comment: So, to solve the original integral what do I have to do?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{(y-x)^2 + \epsilon^2}$ approaches $|y - x|$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, not the $y - x$ that's in the original integrand.

Answer (score 2):

As the others say,simply integrate by avoiding singular points?

Fixed.

## Try other integral.

---

```
target = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, 
   x/\[Sqrt](1 - x) \[Sqrt](1 - y^2)/(y - x)];
integrand[x_, y_] := If[Or[(1 - x) == 0, y == x], 0, target[x, y]];
Quiet@NIntegrate[integrand[x, y], {x, -1., 1.}, {y, -1., 1.}]
```

=>

```
-4.06259
```

> Integration by manual

.

```
Plus @@ Flatten@
  Table[integrand[x, y]*0.001*0.001, {x, -1., 1., 0.001}, {y, -1., 1.,
     0.001}]
```

=>

```
-3.99866
```

> Integration by NIntegrate

```
N@Integrate[
  x/Sqrt[1 - x] Sqrt[1 - y^2]/(y - x), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PrincipalValue -> True]
```

=>

```
-4.14669
```

---

## the question's integral.

```
target = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, 
   x^2/\[Sqrt](1 - x^2) \[Sqrt](1 - y^2)/(y - x)];
integrand[x_, y_] := If[Or[(1 - x^2) == 0, y == x], 0, target[x, y]];
Quiet@NIntegrate[integrand[x, y], {x, -1., 1.}, {y, -1., 1.}]
```

=>

```
-0.4542
```

> By manual.

```
Plus @@ Flatten@
  Table[integrand[x, y]*0.1*0.1, {x, -1., 1., 0.1}, {y, -1., 1., 0.1}]
```

=>

```
-8.88178*10^-16
```

> By other method.

```
Quiet@NIntegrate[integrand[x, y], {x, -1., 1.}, {y, -1., 1.}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

=>

```
7.73766*10^-17
```

For now, we can see that the integral value is close to zero.

Comment: But I can't avoid the singularity $x==y$, because for example if I have $x$ instead of $x^2$ the result of integral is $-\pi^2/2$, and with your code the result is always 0.

Comment: @JavierAlaminos　as your point,my code was always 0. it's mainly because my code returns `Nothing` when the condition met,I think. so just modified.